# Detect whether iOS app is running Debug or Release build without preprocessor macros, for unit testing purposes?

Tags: ios, xcode, macros

I've seen plenty of answers and am familiar with using something preprocessor macros to check whether I'm in debug or release mode, but I'm keen to unit test around those scenarios, so I'd love a way to check that that I could mock.

Can we detect debug, ad hoc or release without using an `#if defined`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a key `configuration` in info.plist with value `${CONFIGURATION}`. Make sure path for your plist file is set in you project build settings. See images below for reference.

[image: plist image]

[image: info.plist link image]

You can then access infoDictionary to get the configuration. Code is below

```
let bundle : NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let configuration : String = (bundle.infoDictionary!["configuration"] as! String)  // configuration is key you set in plist file
```

`configuration` will be a string storing build configuration set in your scheme.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you :)